# SASS - watch folder then output to css file in current directory

Tags: css, sass

I can use sass --watch to watch a /sass folder then output a .css file to a /css folder.

e.g. sass --watch sass:css

this creates main.css in a /css folder.

However I would like to create a file called style.css in the current directory. If I try sass --watch sass:style.css I get main.css created in a /style.css folder.

How do I generate an output file called style.css in the current directory from a /sass folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried: `sass --watch sass:.` ?

Comment: aha, thanks! That puts main.css in the current directory, I changed the name of my sass file to style.scss so that the output file was called style.css. Is there any way to specify the name of the output file using the sass watch command?

Comment: Try using `sass --watch sass:./yourname.css`

Comment: ah, that still creates a folder with the name "yourname.css" for me. That's OK I can work with changing the source file name. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Ok, you're welcome....however, I'd recommend you using a Gulp based build (or maybe an external tool) which can give you the flexibility you want.... with Gulp I've done what you want to achieve, without complications.